# Graphics Disposal error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I added this xml to my drawables :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
      android:radius="2dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

So i could add a background to a linearlayout and relative layout on two separate XMls in Layout folder:

> android:background="@drawable/custom_border"

Although the project runs fine I cannot access any file within it, just recurrent errors in error log:

> Unhandled loop exception org.eclipse.swt.SWTException.error: Graphis
>   is disposed .....

I have deleted the xml drawable file above and all references to it and the error persists. 
Searching this error I could not find much, I even had this error in a previous project where I had to delete it and start from scratch (I also posted that on SO).

Can anyone shed light on this error?

Thanks
Ciaran

Answer (score 0):

Never found a solution or a cause to this error after extensive searching on the net.
However updating the workspace version from a SVN or deleting the project and importing from a saved version elsewhere resolved it. 
Hope this helps for those who encounter this error as it is a headache!!